# unable to do default bean validation with glassfish

Tags: java, spring, maven, glassfish, jersey-2.0

Im developing a Spring based app and using jersey framework.
Im totally new to these technologies. 
I'm trying to use the default validation options like (eg: @valid, @size)
but it is not working for me. Even though it wont return an exception the payload does not get validated.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAXServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.internal</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAXServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Interface layer**

```
public interface EmplyeeService {

public Response getRoleDetails(@NotNull(message = "name cannot be null") 
                                String empName,
                                @Size(max = 8) @QueryParam("empDomain")
                                String empDomain);
```

}

**Implementation layer**

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/employee")
public class EmplyeeImpl implements EmplyeeService {

    @Override
    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    public Response getRoleDetails(@NotNull(message = "name cannot be null") 
                                    String empName,
                                    @Size(max = 8) @QueryParam("empDomain")
                                    String empDomain) {
        return Response.ok().entity().build();
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your webservice is written as Spring web service then you need to create a Model class:

```
public class User {
@NotNull
@Size(min = 6, max = 15)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 6, max = 15)
private String password;

// getters and setters

}
```

And annotations in your controller/service class should look something like this:

```
public Response getRoleDetails(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    // login logic here
}
```

The BindingResult object will give you the validation errors in the form data.
[Check this example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/12/spring-bean-validation-example-with-jsr-303-annotations/)

In case of Jersey web service check [Bean Validation Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this.. any idea on validating the query params with annotations??

Comment: is there a feature in javax that we could you the inbuilt validations? without using the BindingResult object??